# Induced dipole moment and 'electronic polarization'

Tags: theory, materials

Principles of Electronic Materials and Devices - Hasap, pg: 586, he says:

> The induced dipole moment depends on the electric field causing it. We define a quantity called the polarizability a to relate the induced dipole moment \$p_{induced}\$ to the field E causing it,
>
> $$p_{induced} = \alpha \cdot E$$
>
> where \$\alpha\$ is a coefficient called the polarizability of the atom. It depends on the polarization mechanism. Since the polarization of a neutral atom involves the displacement of electrons, \$\alpha\$ is called electronic polarization and denoted as \$\alpha_e\$.

He has already defined dipole moment to be:

$$p = Q \cdot a $$

where \$a\$ is the distance vector from - to +

1. What is the difference between dipole moment and induced dipole moment?
2. He's saying that \$p_{induced}\$ is proportional to polarizability and \$E\$ so
   \$p_{induced} = E \cdot \alpha\$. But dipole moment is also dependent on polarizability.

What's going on?

Comment: I had to roll back a previous edit for formatting as the changes used the cross product for multiply, Q and Alpha are **NOT** vector quantities, so it was an invalid edit.

Comment: @placeholder - you mean that using \times for scalar multiplication is wrong in this case? I've replaced that by \cdot. Is that correct? If not, what is the correct formatting?

Comment: @Ricardo You don't have to have any symbol in there of course, but a dot is fine as well.  Because you are potentially dealing with vector quantities you can't use the \times as it means a cross product.  Your new edit is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's no difference basically, induced dipole moment is just the dipole moment which gets induced when the electronic cloud in an atom is no more symmetric about the nucleus due the external electric fields, consider this - you have an atom FIXED in a place so that its nucleus cant move(just assume it) and you bring a negative charge near it which repels the electrons slightly away from the nucleus and this new distorted atom can now just be considered as a dipole with a +ve charge(nucleus) and negative charge(displaced electronic cloud) though its not a point charge as you might have seen in most pictures of a dipole but effectively it behaves like one,
2. now dipole moment is proportional to the alpha, which means keeping the external field constant the atom with larger alpha will have larger dipole moment(p = Qa = alpha*E), alpha is the property of the elements/compounds,  if an atom has large alpha it just means that its electronic cloud would go more far from its stable configuration and hence large distance between -q and +q which will induce a large value of dipole moment than that of an atom with small alpha,